# JQModal problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmodal

I use jqModal, I had images, and when I click on image need modal window with bigger image.
I make it like that:

```
<div class="catalog-pages-image clearer clearfix">
            <?php foreach ($sorted as $page): ?>
                <a jqModal="id-<?php echo $page['value_id']; ?>" href="javascript:void(0)" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"
                   rel="<?php echo $this->helper('adaptiveResize/image')->init($_product, 'image', $page->getFile())
                       ->setCropPosition('center')
                       ->adaptiveResize(227, 318); ?>">
                    <img src="" height="318" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"/></a>
                <div id="jqModal" class="jqmWindow" style="display: none">
                        <?php var_dump($page->getFile()); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
```

Jquery:

```
Query('#jqModal')
                    .jqm({overlay: 0, trigger: false})
                    //.jqDrag()

                jQuery('.catalog-pages-image').children().click(function () {
                    jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('jqModal')).jqmShow();
                });
```

CSS:

```
.jqmWindow {
    display: none;

    position: fixed;
    top: 17%;
    left: 50%;

    background-color: #EEE;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 12px;
}

.jqmOverlay { background-color: #000; }
```

I can't create fiddle, cause of foreach from PHP.

Probably problem in this :

```
jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('jqModal')).jqmShow();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('.catalog-pages-image a').click(function () {
                    jQuery('#jqModal').html(jQuery(this).attr("rel"));
                    jQuery('#jqModal').jqmShow();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 jQuery('.catalog-pages-image a').click(function () {
     jQuery(this).next().jqmShow();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined, only first link is working